# proxies and urls in python urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, urllib2

Here is my code but it is giving me some error which i an unable to solve it. Even though same code is running fine with a single url and a single proxy but it is not running for the file of proxy and urls .

```
import urllib2
import time 
#bangalore, boston,china

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print "list of urls",urls
with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    for proxy in proxies:
        print proxy
        proxy = proxy.rstrip()
        print proxy
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        try:
            for url in urls:
                request=urllib2.Request(url)
                start=time.time()
                try:
                    print "from try block"
                    response=urllib2.urlopen(urls[0])
                    response.read(1)
                    ttfb = time.time() - start
                    print "Latency:", ttfb
                    print "Status Code:", response.code
                    print "Headers:", response.headers
                    print "Redirected url:", response.url  
                except urllib2.URLError as e:
                    print "From except"
                    print "Error Reason:", e.reason
                    print "Error Message:", e.message
                   # print "Redirected URL:", e.url
                except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                    print e.reason 
        except Exception,e:
            print e
```

Comment: urls.txt is like : 'http://www.google.com' and proxies.txt is : {'http':'ipaddress:8000'}

Comment: You're trying to load strings into the proxy handler, try loading the lines in proxies.txt using json.loads to create dict objects. also the format should be {"http" : "http://ip_address:port"} I think. Might be other issues as well

Comment: also `response=urllib2.urlopen(urls[0])` should be `response=urllib2.urlopen(url)` ?

Comment: yes ..i think that's typing mistake. it is as resonse = urllib2.urlopen(url)

Comment: as u told me the above thing load using json.load() already tried that.. and it is giving me an error as     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: that's a json load error, make sure your proxies.txt file uses double quotes not single as in my post below

Comment: yes it worked ...but jst after putting url without any quoting...thanks a lot...:) i m new in python so will u suggest me some way to be gud in that(python) once again thanks :)

Comment: ok great, if the answer helped can you vote and mark it? thanks

Comment: sorry to say but right now i don't have enough credit to vote for it ...as stackoverflow is saying... will u give me some suggestion for python ...plz ...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this:

```
proxy = json.loads(proxy.rstrip())
```

(and import json)

urls.txt lines are like:

> `http://www.google.com`

proxies.txt lines are like:

> `{"http" : "http://ip:port"}`

also this will always refer to the first url as per my comment on your post:

```
response=urllib2.urlopen(urls[0])
```